# Бот выдаёт ошибку TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, как исправить

Tags: python

```
import telebot
import buttoon as kb
import Database as db


bot = telebot.TeleBot('5675269476:AAEqtwGUDCumaX2W8sbSZt3RwaQ_tskJqmk')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    if db.check_user(message.from_user.id):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы можете ознакомиться со следующими пунктами', reply_markup=kb.teachers())
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, a)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Здрасвуйте, вас приветствует бот созданый для связи с Петром Владимировичем, для последующей связи пожалуйста отправьте своё имя')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name)
def get_name(message):
    user_name = message.text

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Пожалуйста отправьте номер телефона с помощью кнопки', reply_markup=kb.get_number_kb())
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_number, user_name)


def get_number(message, user_name):

    if message.contact:
        user_number = message.contact.phone_number

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Вы успешно зарегестрированы, пожалуйста перезапустите бота, с помощью кнопки', reply_markup=kb.srat())
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name, user_number)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Повторяем, пожалуйста отправьте контакт, используя кнопку')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_number, user_name)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def a(message):
    if message.text == "Связаться с Петром Владимировичем":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Пётр Владимирович свяжется с вами в течении 24 часов")
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'С вами хочет связаться {message.from_user.username or message.from_user.first_name}')
    elif message.text == "Узнать график Петра Владимировича":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Пару минут')

bot.polling()
```

Comment: Приведите ошибку полностью. В какой строке хотя бы? И что в файле `buttoon`, что такое `kb.srat()`, может там скобки лишние?

Comment: зачем вы креды светите?